# Running EXE from Firefox - in a certain path

Tags: javascript, firefox, batch-file, execute, xpcom

I found the solution to run an executable file (.bat or .exe) from a local html page in Firefox - it is documented very well [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIProcess#See_also)

However, I need to start the executable in the folder where it is located. My executable is a .bat file (D:\Test\file.bat) and it contains the command:
echo %cd%

When I run it, it prints:

```
C:\Programs\FirefoxPortableLegacy36
```

instead of printing

```
D:\Test
```

Is there any way to specify in the htm/javascript where exactly (in which directory) to start my executable?

thanks.

Comment: You could try to change Firefox's environment to use a different directory for CD with nsIEnvironment.  If you set the environment variable `CD` to the directory of the app you're launching, I would think the app would inherit it and it'll take precedence over the virtual `%CD%`.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIEnvironment

Comment: If you're always launching batch files, you can just have your batch file change the current directory.  Start the batch file with `pushd "%~dp0"` and end it with `popd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to make the working directory set to the directory where your batch script is? If this is the case then just add this line right in the beginning of your batch script:

```
pushd "%~dp0"
```

You can also read the commandline help for the `for` command. It explains the parameter replacement well.